# How to check the current keyboard's language using VB 6 always time?

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check the current keyboard's language using vb6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580767/how-to-check-the-current-keyboards-language-using-vb6)

How to check the current keyboard's language using VB 6 always time?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer() 
IF (language = EN) Then 
label1.caption = EN 
else ...... 
End IF
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using WMI it could done very easily:

***The function***

```
Public Function GetPropValue(PropName$) As String
    Dim result$
    result = ""
    Set WMIObjectSet = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT *FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each WMIObject In WMIObjectSet
        If result <> "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            For Each WMIProperty In WMIObject.Properties_
                If WMIProperty.Name = PropName Then
                    result = WMIProperty.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    GetPropValue = result
End Function
```

**could be called like:**

```
GetPropValue("OSLanguage")
1033
```

Now it has to check the value with Code Page numbers. For details visit [here](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Lo....asp?s=decimal).

Or

```
Private Declare Function GetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub Timer1_Timer() 
IF (GetThreadLocale = 1033) Then 
    label1.caption="EN"
else
    'check other values
End IF
End Sub
```