# Get current culture in VB6

Tags: vb6

How do I get current culture in VB6? I need to be able to determine where the application is running so that I can format dates appropriately.

For example:

```
if culture = US or CA or MX
   dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
else
   dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Comment: http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetThreadLocale.shtml

Comment: That just gives me a compile-time error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the current keyboard's language using VB 6 always time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702817/how-to-check-the-current-keyboards-language-using-vb-6-always-time)

Comment: I've just tried that linked question with the old MS VB6 and I get the ID correctly as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a

Comment: Martheen, I'm not a VB guy and so I was just making a mistake. I needed to put the declaration up at the top of the file, whereas I had it down below before (between other subs) and that's why I was getting the error. It does, indeed, work. Since you answered first, if you want to put that as the answer, I will mark it as the answer. Otherwise, I will Mark Brian's reply as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows API can provide culture information fairly easily:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY As Long = &H1002  'english name of country
Private Const LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME As Long = &H7 'abbreviated country name

Private Declare Function GetSystemDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Public Sub Test()
   Dim LCID As Long
   Dim Name As String
   
   'you could use the locale id; the US is 1033
   LCID = GetSystemDefaultLCID()
   
   'or convert the locale id to an abbreviation, such as USA
   Name = GetUserLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME)
   
   'or convert the locale id to a name, such as United States
   Name = GetUserLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY)
End Sub

Public Function GetUserLocaleInfo(ByVal dwLocaleID As Long, ByVal dwLCType As Long) As String
   Dim Data As String
   Dim r As Long

   r = GetLocaleInfoA(dwLocaleID, dwLCType, Data, Len(Data))
    
   If r Then
      Data = Space$(r)
      r = GetLocaleInfoA(dwLocaleID, dwLCType, Data, Len(Data))
     
      If r Then
         GetUserLocaleInfo = Left$(Data, r - 1)
      End If
   End If
End Function
```